# How to use Left join instead of inner join

Tags: sql-server, join

I have written the following query, that joins a table with already joined tables. I have basically used inner join using SQL Server. I am wondering how to modify the below code to use Left join rather than inner join?

The below query has three tables Blended, BOUND_TAB and RECORD

The second thing is, I also need to filter the results such that I  use policies with deductibleinUSD > 0 in 'Blended' table or Primary_R Type = 'Deductible' and Primary_R Amount > 0 from the inner select. This should provide me the  policies in  my final results if either 'Blended' or 'BOUND_TAB' indicates that it has a deductible.

```
select
    c.MPolicyNumber,
    c.SNumber,
    c.InsuredName,
    c.EffDate,
    c.Renewal,
    c.GPremiumUSD,
    c.Status,
    c.deductibleinUSD, t.*
from 
    IT.dbo.Blended c 
inner join
    (select distinct 
         a.[Policy Number], a.[LOB],
         a.[Primary_R Amount] as Bound_deductibles,
         a.[Primary_R Type],
         a.[EffDate] as CAS_EffDate
     from 
         IT.dbo.BOUND_TAB a
     inner join 
         IT.dbo.RECORD b on a.idxFile = b.[Bound Rater]
     where 
         a.[Primary Retention Amount] > 0) t on t.[Policy Number] = c.MPolicyNumber
where 
    c.deductibleinUSD > 0 
    and c.ProductLine in ('Health','Cas')
order by 
    c.EffDate
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: For your first 'question': why do you need `LEFT OUTER JOIN`? what prevents you to just replace  `INNER` in your query? For your second question: just specify those filters in your `WHERE` clause. Now, is `ProductLine` inclusive with the other filters or just with `deductibleUSD`?

Answer (score 2):

Without example data and an example of desired results, this is the best I can guess based on your question:

```
select
    c.MPolicyNumber
  , c.SNumber
  , c.InsuredName
  , c.EffDate
  , c.Renewal
  , c.GPremiumUSD
  , c.Status
  , c.deductibleinUSD
  , t.*
from IT.dbo.Blended c 
  left join (
    select distinct 
        a.[Policy Number]
      , a.[LOB]
      , a.[Primary_R Amount] as Bound_deductibles
      , a.[Primary_R Type]
      , a.[EffDate] as CAS_EffDate
    from IT.dbo.BOUND_TAB a
      inner join IT.dbo.RECORD b
        on a.idxFile = b.[Bound Rater]
    where a.[Primary Retention Amount] > 0
  ) as t 
    on t.[Policy Number] = c.MPolicyNumber
   and c.ProductLine in ('Health','Cas')
   and (c.deductibleinUSD > 0
      or (Primary_R Type = 'Deductible'
        and Bound_deductibles > 0
        )
    )
order by c.EffDate
```